# Apply a function to an array of data and save result in another array

Tags: r

I tried this on two different occasions. I wanted to demonstrate overfitting and tinker around with power analysis.
I generated some data with only five points and wanted to demonstrate how you can get a perfect fit but a bad model:

```
a<-4
b<-1
n<-5
x<-c(1:n)
y=a * x+b+rnorm(n,0,100)

model1=lm(y~x)
model2=lm(y~poly(x,2))
model3=lm(y~poly(x,3))
model4=lm(y~poly(x,4))
```

however, I bet there is a way to do this more elegantly, all that I could figure out was to use sapply() in some way:

```
modeldat=c(1:4)
model[i]=sapply(modeldat,function(i) model2=lm(y~poly(x,i)))
```

So after tinkering around, I got no results and just stuck to the "solution" shown above.
Now, today I played around with the "pwr" library to calculate the sample size needed for some hypothetical data. This is the ugly solution I came up with and I bet there is some way to do it with sapply() as well. Doing it like this, however:

```
test=(seq(0,1,by=0.1))
power<-function(x){
  pwr.t.test(,d=coensD,sig.level=0.05,power=x,type="two.sample")
}
sapply(test,power)
```

only produces an error:

> Error in uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2 + 1e-10,
> 1e+09)) :    f() values at end points not of opposite sign

so after googling around for about two hours I am none the wiser and did this...

```
plist=0
powerList=pwr.t.test(,d=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.8,type="two.sample")
plist[1]=powerList$n
powerList=pwr.t.test(,d=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.7,type="two.sample")
plist[2]=powerList$n
powerList=pwr.t.test(,d=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.6,type="two.sample")
plist[3]=powerList$n
powerList=pwr.t.test(,d=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.5,type="two.sample")
plist[4]=powerList$n
powerList=pwr.t.test(,d=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.4,type="two.sample")
plist[5]=powerList$n
```

In both cases I want to apply a function to an array of values and store them in another array. Is there an obvious and easy way to do this?

Comment: This appears to be a question about how to code something in R (the question you're asking doesn't relate to the statistical problem you're writing code for but only to how to best do a particular thing in R code - with details of the language). It doesn't seem to require any statistical expertise to answer, just facility with R. Such questions are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Would you like this migrated to StackOverflow? It looks like you have a reproducible example so it might be suitable for that site.

Comment: Alternatively if you think there's an inherently statistical issue here perhaps you could clarify that.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying! Sorry about that. Can I move it there myself or do I have to create it as a new question?

Comment: The correct procedure is to flag it for migration and a moderator will fix it. I'll do that in a few minutes, hang on.

Comment: Try `lapply(2:4, function(i) lm(y~poly(x, i)))`

Comment: Thanks! It worked for both cases!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(model = c(1:4))
apply(df[,1,drop=F],1,function(i) lm(y~poly(x,i)))
```